# How to calculate date of birth, given age expressed in years, months, days, as reported on a given date?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a 2 months old dataset, from 15 October 2020, containing the ages of different persons. The age of each person is given in years, months, days.

### Example

**Input**: Reference date = 15 October 2020

One entry in the input data set could be:

- **Input:** Age = 21 years, 0 months, 10 days
- **Corresponding output:** Date of Birth = 25 September 1999

This takes into account that their age was reported on 15 October 2020.

I have to convert this data set to get the Date of Birth of each person. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is this an assignment that has certain restrictions as to which features/libraries you can use?

Comment: @trincot I have to do in Python for Data Science and there is no restriction.

Comment: @TomGebel please kindly edit for me.

Comment: What does *"with respect to current date"* mean in your final phrase? A date of birth is a date of birth, independent of the current date, right?

Comment: @trincot since the age given in years, months, days of a person is of 15th Oct 2020 and today's date is 23rd Dec 2020

Comment: @trincot the only problem is that the dataset is very big and coding it takes lots of time in execution. I am looking for a code using some libraries where it gets executed fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`dateutil.relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) function, which you can use to subtract years, months and days from another date.

I'll assume that you know the exact date on which the data was collected, ... let's say 15 October 2020:

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

# Let's say the data was taken on 15 October 2020:
refdate = date(2020, 10, 15)

# The data itself: triplets of years, months, days as collected on 15 October 2020:
data = [
    [20, 2, 1],
    [53, 5, 10],
]

# Extend the data with the birthdate:
for person in data:
    person.append(refdate - relativedelta(years=person[0],
                                          months=person[1], 
                                          days=person[2]))

# Print the data:
for person in data:
    print("{} years, {} months, {} days: born on {}".format(*person))
```

Comment: My apology. Actually I was trying to understand the logic in your code and I got confused. Thank you very much for your help.